# AngularJS – how to sort array of unix epoch time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an array of unix epoch time which I am converting to GMT string. I want to sort the array, how can I go about it?

```
for(var i in data.results) {
    var date = new Date(data.results[i].lastModifiedAt*1000);
    var day = date.toGMTString();
    $scope.day[i] = day;
}
```

Comment: `$scope.day.sort()` should work

Answer (score 1):

Since you tag the question as angular, you can use `ng-repeat` with `orderBy`. Something like:

```
$scope.results = data.results.map(function(result) {
  result.day = new Date(result.lastModifiedAt*1000).toGMTString()
  return result;
}
```

And in your html:

`<div ng-repeat="result in results | orderBy:'day':true track by $index"></div>`

And you will not have to use `sort`